# Magento set product status to 'Disabled' when qty = '0' (Out of stock)

Tags: magento

I'm trying to build a Magento store using CE 1.6.2 and I need to set the Product status to "Disabled" when the qty = '0' (Out of stock).  Once a product is sold out, I need it to automatically change the status to disabled as I will never sell this product again. Also once a certain data/time is reached, I'll also need it to automatically disabled the product.

I know Magento offers the option to not show the product once it is sold out but that is not what I'm looking for.  I really need it to disable the product.

OR....

What if instead of disabling the product, when the product is out of stock, is there a way to clear all customers shopping cart of this product.

The problem I"m seeing, is that if a customer has this item in their shopping cart and another customer just bought the last product available, the first customer still sees the item in their shopping cart even though it will not allow them to checkout (since their are no more available).  The only way to empty the cart, is that the customer has to manually remove the product.

So is there a way I can set that when item is out of stock to remove this product from all customer carts?

I'm new to Magento so if anyone can show me the code and how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

You need to develop an extension for this task.
It should be sufficient to create an Observer for the event sales_order_save_after and check the qty. If it is 0, you can disable your product.

Well, I will show you how. Create the following files and clear your caches to make it work (the code is untested, but should work).

/app/code/local/Sebi/DeactivateOnOutOfStock/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <deactivateonoutofstock>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
                    </deactivateonoutofstock>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
        <routers>
            <Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock</module>
                    <frontName>DeactivateOnOutOfStock</frontName>
                </args>
            </Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Sebi/DeactivateOnOutOfStock/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer)
    {
        $storeId = 0; //the admin store view, change this if you want to disable only for the store view from which the order came
        $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            $stockQty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($item->getProductId())->getQty();

            if ($stockQty == 0) {
                Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($item->getProductId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

/app/etc/modules/Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sebi_DeactivateOnOutOfStock>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Good luck! Don't forget to refresh your caches!

Edit: Saw your edit now. I would not remove items from customers' carts when sold out, as they would think of an error and try to find it in your shop. But they can't. This would be very frustrating. If they try to order and the product was sold out while they were ordering, Magento informs them, that the product isn't in stock anymore. This has to be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the code work.  I thought about the second part of my post today.  Basically I'm working on a deal a day site (1 or 2 products a day for 24 hr period of time).  That is all I'll have on my site.  So its not like a true magento store with tons of products.  I believe setting the product to 'Disabled' will also clear the shopping cart if there are any of that product in their cart.  I'm using a one step checkout extension and from what I saw, it did not notify me the product was out of stock when I tried to process the transaction.  This is all on a test account of course

Comment: If I were you, I would work on an extension that will notify the customer, that a product in his cart is now sold out and has been removed. But you should also test first if it really removes disabled products from your cart without telling the customer.